# Add and display days/months/years to date input by user in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to work out how to display a date which is one or more days/months/years in the future from that being input by the user.

For example:

```
<input ng-model="startDate" type="date" id="start-date" name="startDate">
```

Which is to be displayed below:

```
<p>The start and end dates are: {{startDate | date}} and {{endDate() | date}}.</p>
```

The endDate function is as follows:

```
$scope.endDate = function() {
    if($scope.startDate) {
        var endDate = $scope.startDate;
        return endDate.setYear(endDate.getYear() + 1);
    }
}
```

Whilst the startDate displays, the endDate() does not.  This happens whether or not I wrap it in the if statement.

Comment: is `startDate` a Date object? What errors are thrown? What behaviors are expected if user changes start date? Also be aware that `type="date"` is not fully supported cross browser

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using the moment.js library for any AngularJS related date maths. Very easy addition and subtraction etc functions for date objects.

http://momentjs.com/

Example
$scope.date = moment().add(1, 'months') will add a month to the current date.